# asp.net AuthenticationService in iOS

Tags: ios, asp.net

I have been searching for a way to interface iOS application with our asp.net web application.  In order for the app to work, it needs to authenticate users against asp.net user table.  I've tried using wsdl2bjc without any luck (the application crashes without any classes generated), and then I tried posting raw SOAP to the server, but I get a message without any data.

At this point I have hit a wall.  Any help with this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you looked into WebAPI? http://www.asp.net/vnext/overview/authentication/individual-accounts-in-aspnet-web-api

Comment: Can you create a test harness in your ASP app to pass the SOAP packet to your service? At least that way you could debug and try to troubleshoot the error.

Comment: @Tim Unfortunately I don't have access to the web app.

Comment: It sounds like your packet may not be properly formatted. I got this when I was testing and had to tweak the SOAP packet I was sending to the service. (It returns nothing, right?)

Comment: It returns nothing.  I used soapUI-4.6.4 to see the raw response back from the server.  I got an error message in the raw format.

Comment: The message said, HTTP/1.1 415 Cannot process the message because the content type 'application soap+xml; charset=UTF-8; action="http://asp.net/applicationservice/v200/authenticationservice/login" was no the expected type 'application/soap+msbin1'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this in an app (well, I inherited the app from other developers).

What they did was set up a web service to do this - the service validates a user against a table, and returns a boolean indicating whether the user has authenticated or not. Since it's just XML coming back, iOS is totally unaware of how the .NET authentication service works.

It receives an HTTP post of a formatted XML packet from the client. It's relatively simple - username and password.

Debugging this was a painful experience, I need to add.

Comment: Ok, this is a great suggestion.  I will try this.